# Adding array into another array (not array_push or array_merge)

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I am quite new to PHP and I have some problems with pushing arrays to another. For more details, I want to show a part of my code:

This is a sample response data:

edit: I have more than one "sentenceArray"

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "sentenceArray": [
        {
          "path": {
            "type": "walk",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "lat": 39.952614,
                "lng": 32.854491
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.952083,
                "lng": 32.857761
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "path": {
            "type": "bus",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "lat": 39.952418,
                "lng": 32.85727
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.952797,
                "lng": 32.856825
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.953102,
                "lng": 32.856438
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "path": {
            "type": "bus",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "lat": 39.964951,
                "lng": 32.841305
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.964785,
                "lng": 32.841514
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sentenceArray": [
        {
          "path": {
            "type": "walk",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "lat": 39.952614,
                "lng": 32.854491
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.952083,
                "lng": 32.857761
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "path": {
            "type": "bus",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "lat": 39.952418,
                "lng": 32.85727
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.952797,
                "lng": 32.856825
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.953102,
                "lng": 32.856438
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "path": {
            "type": "bus",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "lat": 39.964951,
                "lng": 32.841305
              },
              {
                "lat": 39.964785,
                "lng": 32.841514
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I did so far:

```
for($j = 0; $j < $l; $j++) {
        if($sentenceArray[$j]['path']['type'] == "bus") {
            if(isset($sentenceArray[$j]['path']['nodes'])){
                $busCount++;
                $nodes = $sentenceArray[$j]['path']['nodes'];
                for($k = 0, $c = count($nodes); $k < $c; $k++) {
                    $latlng = $nodes[$k];
                    array_push($arrBus,$latlng);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

At first, I tried to push arrays into one array but my code merged it all in one array, not two separated arrays in one array. By the way, real data is much bigger than this and generated dynamically. So bus array count can be two or more.  It is little bit confusing for me as a newbie PHP developer.

Let me show you what is my goal here:

```js
var lineCoordinates = {
  "0": [
    {
                                "lat": 39.952418,
                                "lng": 32.85727
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 39.952797,
                                "lng": 32.856825
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 39.953102,
                                "lng": 32.856438
                            }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
                                "lat": 39.964951,
                                "lng": 32.841305
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 39.964785,
                                "lng": 32.841514
                            }
                            
                           
  ]
}
```

This sample output will work for me well.

I spend many hours to do this by myself and I also read my posts on web but couldn't find the solution. Please, do not judge me. As I said, I am newbie. Thanks in advance.

By the way, I use json_decode() when I pull data first and I use json_encode() at the end. But I didn't need to mention it.

Comment: so your mission is to filter out the array type bus and represent it on object array format?

Comment: @icecub I am working as a frond-end developer for many years. It is not a school assignment. I am using Google Maps API to draw polylines dynamically. Thats why I need this output. I tested with static data and frontend side works well now. But also I need to code PHP but I have no much experience with it. array_push() puts all data in one. Like that: [{ "lat": 39.955744,"lng": 32.85303},{"lat": 39.956395,"lng": 32.852171},{"lat": 39.955744,"lng": 32.85303},{"lat": 39.956395,“lng": 32.852171}]

with this data, I can't draw seperated polylines on map.

Comment: @sumit That is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the `data` subarray, then iterate the `sentenceArray`, then if the `['path']['type']` value is `bus` and the `['path']['nodes']` subarray exists, then store that subarray as a separate group in the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/89bf8))

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array['data'] as $datas) {
    foreach ($datas['sentenceArray'] as $subitem) {
        if ($subitem['path']['type'] == 'bus' && isset($subitem['path']['nodes'])) {
            $result[] = $subitem['path']['nodes'];
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Output:

```
[[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514}],[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514}]]
```

---

This also work on your full json input string to provide:

```
[[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438},{"lat":39.953273,"lng":32.856239},{"lat":39.953713,"lng":32.855659},{"lat":39.954017,"lng":32.855296},{"lat":39.95498,"lng":32.854037},{"lat":39.955138,"lng":32.853829},{"lat":39.955317,"lng":32.853592},{"lat":39.955448,"lng":32.853421},{"lat":39.955638,"lng":32.853161},{"lat":39.955744,"lng":32.85303},{"lat":39.956395,"lng":32.852171},{"lat":39.957293,"lng":32.851087},{"lat":39.957668,"lng":32.850631},{"lat":39.957715,"lng":32.850579},{"lat":39.957854,"lng":32.850421},{"lat":39.957963,"lng":32.850286},{"lat":39.959664,"lng":32.848184},{"lat":39.960768,"lng":32.846954},{"lat":39.961228,"lng":32.846328},{"lat":39.961566,"lng":32.845869},{"lat":39.962472,"lng":32.844696},{"lat":39.963265,"lng":32.843721},{"lat":39.963397,"lng":32.84357},{"lat":39.963511,"lng":32.843414},{"lat":39.963628,"lng":32.843271},{"lat":39.963804,"lng":32.843048},{"lat":39.963898,"lng":32.842929},{"lat":39.965452,"lng":32.840996}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514},{"lat":39.964555,"lng":32.841818},{"lat":39.963827,"lng":32.842688},{"lat":39.963622,"lng":32.842942},{"lat":39.963542,"lng":32.843037},{"lat":39.96343,"lng":32.843185},{"lat":39.963304,"lng":32.843335},{"lat":39.962502,"lng":32.844327},{"lat":39.961437,"lng":32.845665},{"lat":39.961162,"lng":32.84601},{"lat":39.961054,"lng":32.84613},{"lat":39.960679,"lng":32.846639},{"lat":39.960299,"lng":32.84711},{"lat":39.959572,"lng":32.848031},{"lat":39.959476,"lng":32.848146},{"lat":39.957918,"lng":32.85016},{"lat":39.957835,"lng":32.850267},{"lat":39.957696,"lng":32.850436},{"lat":39.957636,"lng":32.850509},{"lat":39.957244,"lng":32.850993},{"lat":39.95635,"lng":32.852096},{"lat":39.955658,"lng":32.852909},{"lat":39.954229,"lng":32.854682},{"lat":39.953853,"lng":32.855119},{"lat":39.953422,"lng":32.85567},{"lat":39.953096,"lng":32.856053},{"lat":39.952949,"lng":32.856252},{"lat":39.952406,"lng":32.856964},{"lat":39.952278,"lng":32.857091},{"lat":39.951554,"lng":32.857753},{"lat":39.951114,"lng":32.857934},{"lat":39.950962,"lng":32.857907},{"lat":39.950826,"lng":32.857881},{"lat":39.950556,"lng":32.857782},{"lat":39.94987,"lng":32.857458},{"lat":39.948744,"lng":32.856459},{"lat":39.948303,"lng":32.856178},{"lat":39.947866,"lng":32.855815},{"lat":39.947623,"lng":32.855625},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.946974,"lng":32.855249},{"lat":39.946209,"lng":32.854963},{"lat":39.945342,"lng":32.854679},{"lat":39.945094,"lng":32.85462},{"lat":39.944673,"lng":32.854562},{"lat":39.944124,"lng":32.854557},{"lat":39.943877,"lng":32.854564},{"lat":39.943572,"lng":32.854576},{"lat":39.943336,"lng":32.854503},{"lat":39.943041,"lng":32.854494},{"lat":39.942475,"lng":32.854465},{"lat":39.942371,"lng":32.85444},{"lat":39.942294,"lng":32.854403},{"lat":39.94201,"lng":32.854252},{"lat":39.941672,"lng":32.854101},{"lat":39.941495,"lng":32.854233},{"lat":39.940512,"lng":32.854229}],[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438},{"lat":39.953273,"lng":32.856239},{"lat":39.953713,"lng":32.855659},{"lat":39.954017,"lng":32.855296},{"lat":39.95498,"lng":32.854037},{"lat":39.955138,"lng":32.853829},{"lat":39.955317,"lng":32.853592},{"lat":39.955448,"lng":32.853421},{"lat":39.955638,"lng":32.853161},{"lat":39.955744,"lng":32.85303},{"lat":39.956395,"lng":32.852171},{"lat":39.957293,"lng":32.851087},{"lat":39.957668,"lng":32.850631},{"lat":39.957715,"lng":32.850579},{"lat":39.957854,"lng":32.850421},{"lat":39.957963,"lng":32.850286},{"lat":39.959664,"lng":32.848184},{"lat":39.960768,"lng":32.846954},{"lat":39.961228,"lng":32.846328},{"lat":39.961566,"lng":32.845869},{"lat":39.962472,"lng":32.844696},{"lat":39.963265,"lng":32.843721},{"lat":39.963397,"lng":32.84357},{"lat":39.963511,"lng":32.843414},{"lat":39.963628,"lng":32.843271},{"lat":39.963804,"lng":32.843048},{"lat":39.963898,"lng":32.842929},{"lat":39.965452,"lng":32.840996}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514},{"lat":39.964555,"lng":32.841818},{"lat":39.963827,"lng":32.842688},{"lat":39.963622,"lng":32.842942},{"lat":39.963542,"lng":32.843037},{"lat":39.96343,"lng":32.843185},{"lat":39.963304,"lng":32.843335},{"lat":39.962502,"lng":32.844327},{"lat":39.961437,"lng":32.845665},{"lat":39.961162,"lng":32.84601},{"lat":39.961054,"lng":32.84613},{"lat":39.960679,"lng":32.846639},{"lat":39.960299,"lng":32.84711},{"lat":39.959572,"lng":32.848031},{"lat":39.959476,"lng":32.848146},{"lat":39.957918,"lng":32.85016},{"lat":39.957835,"lng":32.850267},{"lat":39.957696,"lng":32.850436},{"lat":39.957636,"lng":32.850509},{"lat":39.957244,"lng":32.850993},{"lat":39.95635,"lng":32.852096},{"lat":39.955658,"lng":32.852909},{"lat":39.954229,"lng":32.854682},{"lat":39.953422,"lng":32.85567},{"lat":39.953096,"lng":32.856053},{"lat":39.952949,"lng":32.856252},{"lat":39.952406,"lng":32.856964},{"lat":39.952278,"lng":32.857091},{"lat":39.951554,"lng":32.857753},{"lat":39.951114,"lng":32.857934},{"lat":39.950962,"lng":32.857907},{"lat":39.950826,"lng":32.857881},{"lat":39.950556,"lng":32.857782},{"lat":39.94987,"lng":32.857458},{"lat":39.948744,"lng":32.856459},{"lat":39.948303,"lng":32.856178},{"lat":39.947866,"lng":32.855815},{"lat":39.947623,"lng":32.855625},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.946974,"lng":32.855249},{"lat":39.946209,"lng":32.854963},{"lat":39.945342,"lng":32.854679},{"lat":39.945094,"lng":32.85462},{"lat":39.944673,"lng":32.854562},{"lat":39.944124,"lng":32.854557},{"lat":39.943877,"lng":32.854564},{"lat":39.943572,"lng":32.854576},{"lat":39.943336,"lng":32.854503},{"lat":39.943041,"lng":32.854494},{"lat":39.942475,"lng":32.854465},{"lat":39.942371,"lng":32.85444},{"lat":39.942294,"lng":32.854403},{"lat":39.94201,"lng":32.854252},{"lat":39.941672,"lng":32.854101},{"lat":39.941495,"lng":32.854233},{"lat":39.940512,"lng":32.854229}],[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438},{"lat":39.953273,"lng":32.856239},{"lat":39.953713,"lng":32.855659},{"lat":39.954017,"lng":32.855296},{"lat":39.95498,"lng":32.854037},{"lat":39.955138,"lng":32.853829},{"lat":39.955317,"lng":32.853592},{"lat":39.955448,"lng":32.853421},{"lat":39.955638,"lng":32.853161},{"lat":39.955744,"lng":32.85303},{"lat":39.956395,"lng":32.852171},{"lat":39.957293,"lng":32.851087},{"lat":39.957668,"lng":32.850631},{"lat":39.957715,"lng":32.850579},{"lat":39.957854,"lng":32.850421},{"lat":39.957963,"lng":32.850286},{"lat":39.959664,"lng":32.848184},{"lat":39.960768,"lng":32.846954},{"lat":39.961228,"lng":32.846328},{"lat":39.961566,"lng":32.845869},{"lat":39.962472,"lng":32.844696},{"lat":39.963265,"lng":32.843721},{"lat":39.963397,"lng":32.84357},{"lat":39.963511,"lng":32.843414},{"lat":39.963628,"lng":32.843271},{"lat":39.963804,"lng":32.843048},{"lat":39.963898,"lng":32.842929},{"lat":39.965452,"lng":32.840996}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514},{"lat":39.964555,"lng":32.841818},{"lat":39.963827,"lng":32.842688},{"lat":39.963622,"lng":32.842942},{"lat":39.963542,"lng":32.843037},{"lat":39.96343,"lng":32.843185},{"lat":39.963304,"lng":32.843335},{"lat":39.962502,"lng":32.844327},{"lat":39.961437,"lng":32.845665},{"lat":39.961162,"lng":32.84601},{"lat":39.961054,"lng":32.84613},{"lat":39.960679,"lng":32.846639},{"lat":39.960299,"lng":32.84711},{"lat":39.959572,"lng":32.848031},{"lat":39.959476,"lng":32.848146},{"lat":39.957918,"lng":32.85016},{"lat":39.957835,"lng":32.850267},{"lat":39.957696,"lng":32.850436},{"lat":39.957636,"lng":32.850509},{"lat":39.957244,"lng":32.850993},{"lat":39.95635,"lng":32.852096},{"lat":39.955658,"lng":32.852909},{"lat":39.954229,"lng":32.854682},{"lat":39.953853,"lng":32.855119},{"lat":39.953422,"lng":32.85567},{"lat":39.953096,"lng":32.856053},{"lat":39.952949,"lng":32.856252},{"lat":39.952406,"lng":32.856964},{"lat":39.952278,"lng":32.857091},{"lat":39.951554,"lng":32.857753},{"lat":39.951114,"lng":32.857934},{"lat":39.950962,"lng":32.857907},{"lat":39.950826,"lng":32.857881},{"lat":39.950556,"lng":32.857782},{"lat":39.94987,"lng":32.857458},{"lat":39.948744,"lng":32.856459},{"lat":39.948303,"lng":32.856178},{"lat":39.947866,"lng":32.855815},{"lat":39.947623,"lng":32.855625},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.946974,"lng":32.855249},{"lat":39.946209,"lng":32.854963},{"lat":39.945342,"lng":32.854679},{"lat":39.945094,"lng":32.85462},{"lat":39.944673,"lng":32.854562},{"lat":39.944124,"lng":32.854557},{"lat":39.943877,"lng":32.854564},{"lat":39.943572,"lng":32.854576},{"lat":39.943336,"lng":32.854503},{"lat":39.943041,"lng":32.854494},{"lat":39.942475,"lng":32.854465},{"lat":39.942371,"lng":32.85444},{"lat":39.942294,"lng":32.854403},{"lat":39.94201,"lng":32.854252},{"lat":39.941672,"lng":32.854101},{"lat":39.941495,"lng":32.854233},{"lat":39.940512,"lng":32.854229}],[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438},{"lat":39.953273,"lng":32.856239},{"lat":39.953713,"lng":32.855659},{"lat":39.954017,"lng":32.855296},{"lat":39.95498,"lng":32.854037},{"lat":39.955138,"lng":32.853829},{"lat":39.955317,"lng":32.853592},{"lat":39.955448,"lng":32.853421},{"lat":39.955638,"lng":32.853161},{"lat":39.955744,"lng":32.85303},{"lat":39.956395,"lng":32.852171},{"lat":39.957293,"lng":32.851087},{"lat":39.957668,"lng":32.850631},{"lat":39.957715,"lng":32.850579},{"lat":39.957854,"lng":32.850421},{"lat":39.957963,"lng":32.850286},{"lat":39.959664,"lng":32.848184},{"lat":39.960768,"lng":32.846954},{"lat":39.961228,"lng":32.846328},{"lat":39.961566,"lng":32.845869},{"lat":39.962472,"lng":32.844696},{"lat":39.963265,"lng":32.843721},{"lat":39.963397,"lng":32.84357},{"lat":39.963511,"lng":32.843414},{"lat":39.963628,"lng":32.843271},{"lat":39.963804,"lng":32.843048},{"lat":39.963898,"lng":32.842929},{"lat":39.965452,"lng":32.840996}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514},{"lat":39.964555,"lng":32.841818},{"lat":39.963827,"lng":32.842688},{"lat":39.963622,"lng":32.842942},{"lat":39.963542,"lng":32.843037},{"lat":39.96343,"lng":32.843185},{"lat":39.963304,"lng":32.843335},{"lat":39.962502,"lng":32.844327},{"lat":39.961437,"lng":32.845665},{"lat":39.961162,"lng":32.84601},{"lat":39.961054,"lng":32.84613},{"lat":39.960679,"lng":32.846639},{"lat":39.960299,"lng":32.84711},{"lat":39.959572,"lng":32.848031},{"lat":39.959476,"lng":32.848146},{"lat":39.957918,"lng":32.85016},{"lat":39.957835,"lng":32.850267},{"lat":39.957696,"lng":32.850436},{"lat":39.957636,"lng":32.850509},{"lat":39.957244,"lng":32.850993},{"lat":39.95635,"lng":32.852096},{"lat":39.955658,"lng":32.852909},{"lat":39.954229,"lng":32.854682},{"lat":39.953853,"lng":32.855119},{"lat":39.953422,"lng":32.85567},{"lat":39.953096,"lng":32.856053},{"lat":39.952949,"lng":32.856252},{"lat":39.952406,"lng":32.856964},{"lat":39.952278,"lng":32.857091},{"lat":39.951554,"lng":32.857753},{"lat":39.951114,"lng":32.857934},{"lat":39.950962,"lng":32.857907},{"lat":39.950826,"lng":32.857881},{"lat":39.950556,"lng":32.857782},{"lat":39.94987,"lng":32.857458},{"lat":39.948744,"lng":32.856459},{"lat":39.948303,"lng":32.856178},{"lat":39.947866,"lng":32.855815},{"lat":39.947623,"lng":32.855625},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.946974,"lng":32.855249},{"lat":39.946209,"lng":32.854963},{"lat":39.945342,"lng":32.854679},{"lat":39.945094,"lng":32.85462},{"lat":39.944673,"lng":32.854562},{"lat":39.944124,"lng":32.854557},{"lat":39.943877,"lng":32.854564},{"lat":39.943572,"lng":32.854576},{"lat":39.943336,"lng":32.854503},{"lat":39.943041,"lng":32.854494},{"lat":39.942475,"lng":32.854465},{"lat":39.942371,"lng":32.85444},{"lat":39.942294,"lng":32.854403},{"lat":39.94201,"lng":32.854252},{"lat":39.941672,"lng":32.854101},{"lat":39.941495,"lng":32.854233},{"lat":39.940512,"lng":32.854229}],[{"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},{"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},{"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438},{"lat":39.953273,"lng":32.856239},{"lat":39.953713,"lng":32.855659},{"lat":39.954017,"lng":32.855296},{"lat":39.95498,"lng":32.854037},{"lat":39.955138,"lng":32.853829},{"lat":39.955317,"lng":32.853592},{"lat":39.955448,"lng":32.853421},{"lat":39.955638,"lng":32.853161},{"lat":39.955744,"lng":32.85303},{"lat":39.956395,"lng":32.852171},{"lat":39.957293,"lng":32.851087},{"lat":39.957668,"lng":32.850631},{"lat":39.957715,"lng":32.850579},{"lat":39.957854,"lng":32.850421},{"lat":39.957963,"lng":32.850286},{"lat":39.959664,"lng":32.848184},{"lat":39.960768,"lng":32.846954},{"lat":39.961228,"lng":32.846328},{"lat":39.961566,"lng":32.845869},{"lat":39.962472,"lng":32.844696},{"lat":39.963265,"lng":32.843721},{"lat":39.963397,"lng":32.84357},{"lat":39.963511,"lng":32.843414},{"lat":39.963628,"lng":32.843271},{"lat":39.963804,"lng":32.843048},{"lat":39.963898,"lng":32.842929},{"lat":39.965452,"lng":32.840996}],[{"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},{"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514},{"lat":39.964555,"lng":32.841818},{"lat":39.963827,"lng":32.842688},{"lat":39.963622,"lng":32.842942},{"lat":39.963542,"lng":32.843037},{"lat":39.96343,"lng":32.843185},{"lat":39.963304,"lng":32.843335},{"lat":39.962502,"lng":32.844327},{"lat":39.961437,"lng":32.845665},{"lat":39.961162,"lng":32.84601},{"lat":39.961054,"lng":32.84613},{"lat":39.960679,"lng":32.846639},{"lat":39.960299,"lng":32.84711},{"lat":39.959572,"lng":32.848031},{"lat":39.959476,"lng":32.848146},{"lat":39.957918,"lng":32.85016},{"lat":39.957835,"lng":32.850267},{"lat":39.957696,"lng":32.850436},{"lat":39.957636,"lng":32.850509},{"lat":39.957244,"lng":32.850993},{"lat":39.95635,"lng":32.852096},{"lat":39.955658,"lng":32.852909},{"lat":39.954229,"lng":32.854682},{"lat":39.953422,"lng":32.85567},{"lat":39.953096,"lng":32.856053},{"lat":39.952949,"lng":32.856252},{"lat":39.952406,"lng":32.856964},{"lat":39.952278,"lng":32.857091},{"lat":39.951554,"lng":32.857753},{"lat":39.951114,"lng":32.857934},{"lat":39.950962,"lng":32.857907},{"lat":39.950826,"lng":32.857881},{"lat":39.950556,"lng":32.857782},{"lat":39.94987,"lng":32.857458},{"lat":39.948744,"lng":32.856459},{"lat":39.948303,"lng":32.856178},{"lat":39.947866,"lng":32.855815},{"lat":39.947623,"lng":32.855625},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.947283,"lng":32.855428},{"lat":39.946974,"lng":32.855249},{"lat":39.946209,"lng":32.854963},{"lat":39.945342,"lng":32.854679},{"lat":39.945094,"lng":32.85462},{"lat":39.944673,"lng":32.854562},{"lat":39.944124,"lng":32.854557},{"lat":39.943877,"lng":32.854564},{"lat":39.943572,"lng":32.854576},{"lat":39.943336,"lng":32.854503},{"lat":39.943041,"lng":32.854494},{"lat":39.942475,"lng":32.854465},{"lat":39.942371,"lng":32.85444},{"lat":39.942294,"lng":32.854403},{"lat":39.94201,"lng":32.854252},{"lat":39.941672,"lng":32.854101},{"lat":39.941495,"lng":32.854233},{"lat":39.940512,"lng":32.854229}]]
```

---

**Question Extension**

To filter the results by user-provided value `seq`:

```
if (!isset($_GET['seq']) || !ctype_digit($_GET['seq'])){
    echo "Missing/Invalid SEQ value.";
} else {
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    $result = [];
    $selected_seq = (int)$_GET['seq'];
    foreach ($array['data'] as $seq => $datas) {
        if ($seq === $selected_seq) {
            foreach ($datas['sentenceArray'] as $subitem) {
                if ($subitem['path']['type'] == 'bus' && isset($subitem['path']['nodes'])) {
                    $result[] = $subitem['path']['nodes'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if my data structure is like that: ibb.co/feyXOy I tried to make my data shorter to paste here, but I forgot the mention one important detail. There is more than one array in data[], can you please check the screenshot?

Comment: My real data is a bit long, stackoverflow don't let me know paste all code into question. But here you can see https://jsfiddle.net/6az6f49c/ by the way many thanks for your explanation, now I get the logic behind here.

Comment: Your responsibility as a question poster, is to isolate and minimize your issue.  This is described in the How to ask a question page.  Please do that.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Sorry about that. I update my question and data.

Comment: @gimmeonereason You don't really need the string/quoted indexes on the result's subarrays do you?

Comment: Actually yes, I need the indexes. By the way I tried your code, it worked but when I work with real data, it shows all the sentenceArray's nodes. In my php code, I want to access only given sentenceArray's nodes. Lets say $seq = $_GET['seq']; and if $seq = 0, I need to return only data[0].sentenceArray. I hope I could explain myself. And I am very sorry if I asked a lot ot things :(

Comment: The point to be careful about is continuously extending your question requirements.  Please be clear about all requirements from the start, so that we aren't dragged into completing an entire project for you.  Let me ask very clearly, you need the subarray indexes to be numbers cast as **strings**?  What is the purpose of string type indexes for your project?

Comment: You are right again, my bad. I am sorry. I need indexes but it doesn't matter it is string or not. I just only need indexes.

Comment: and what behavior do you want when `$_GET['seq']` doesn't match any records or when `$_GET['seq']` is not set?

Comment: if `$_GET['seq']` doesn't match any records or not set, it is not that important. I am working on POC for myself, so we can ignore this case. But FYI, there is always at least 2 sentenceArray.

Comment: Well, a couple of logical behaviors would be to display none of the records when the seq is missing/invalid OR you could display all records ... depends on the project.

Comment: Yes. As I said before, I am making these project just for myself so in these project we can ignore this case. But I still need use that parameter

Comment: I have updated my answer per your question extension

Comment: It works! Many thanks dude! You are the best! And thanks for your time, your explanations and your patience of course.

Comment: @gimmeonereason I wonder why people don't up-vote an answer when they accept it. Up-voting an answer helps those who post helpful solutions to grow in tags the question is tagged with.

Comment: Thanks @revo.  The OP doesn't have upvote privileges.

Comment: @revo Now I have enough rating to up-vote answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @gimmeonereason Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code:

```
 for($j = 0; $j < $l; $j++) {
    if($sentenceArray[$j]['path']['type'] == "bus") {
        $childArr = array();
        if(isset($sentenceArray[$j]['path']['nodes'])){
            foreach($sentenceArray[$j]['path']['nodes'] as $nodes)
            {
                array_push($childArr, $nodes);
            }
        }
        $arrBus[$j] = $childArr;
    }
}

$arrBus = array_values($arrBus);
$arrBus = json_encode($arrBus);
```

Output as below:

```
 [  
   [  
      {  
         "lat":39.952418,
         "lng":32.85727
      },
      {  
         "lat":39.952797,
         "lng":32.856825
      },
      {  
         "lat":39.953102,
         "lng":32.856438
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "lat":39.964951,
         "lng":32.841305
      },
      {  
         "lat":39.964785,
         "lng":32.841514
      }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce the output that you desire (`$json` is assumed to contain the JSON from your first snippet):

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
$buslines = new stdClass();
$routenum = 0;
foreach ($arr->data as $data) {
    foreach ($data->sentenceArray as $route) {
        if (!isset($route->path, $route->path->type, $route->path->nodes)) continue;
        if ($route->path->type != 'bus') continue;
        $buslines->{$routenum} = array();
        foreach ($route->path->nodes as $node) {
            $buslines->{$routenum}[] = $node;
        }
        $routenum++;
    }
}
echo json_encode($buslines);
```

Output:

```
{
  "0": [
        {"lat":39.952418,"lng":32.85727},
        {"lat":39.952797,"lng":32.856825},
        {"lat":39.953102,"lng":32.856438}
       ],
  "1": [
        {"lat":39.964951,"lng":32.841305},
        {"lat":39.964785,"lng":32.841514}
       ]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort. I am sure your code is works. But I tried to make shorter my data on my post, that's why now it gives an error :Trying to get property of non-object" on this line "foreach ($arr->data as $data)". My real data structure is that: https://ibb.co/feyXOy. I tried to edit the code like foreach ($arr->data[0] as $data) but it is also doesn't work. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: That error you're getting means that `$arr` is not an object. I presume you included the `$arr = json_decode($json);` line using whatever variable contains your JSON? If so, that probably means the json_decode failed which would mean the JSON is invalid. If you could post a sample of the real data I'm sure I could make this code work quite quickly.

Comment: I just ran my code on that and it worked perfectly (I got about 500 entries in the output). Can you post the PHP code you have written which incorporates my code?

Comment: That includes the code from a different answer, not mine.